How to reload ONE particular UI script? (an alternative to 'Reload Scripts' )
My add-on edits Blender's UI scripts.
To apply changes to UI - edited scripts should be reloaded.
For this purpose I use bpy.ops.script.reload()
It does the job, but it works kind of slow.
So I wonder: is there any way to reload one specific UI script ?

I thought importlib could do the thing, but appears it cannot...
An illustration:
As a simple example let's edit the script which is responsible for [File] menu tab.
It's space_topbar.py, which is located in :
Blender\4.1\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_topbar.py
For demonstration purposes let's get rid of a [Revert] menu option.
This option is being drawn inside the class TOPBAR_MT_file(Menu)
*in the line 282:
layout.operator("wm.revert_mainfile")


so let's just comment this line :
# layout.operator("wm.revert_mainfile")


*(After saving "space_topbar.py") I'm trying to reload the changed space_topbar module:
1st try:
import sys,importlib
importlib.reload(sys.modules['bl_ui.space_topbar'])

• no effect:


2nd try:
*let's also reload the module's __init__ :
import sys,importlib
importlib.reload(sys.modules['bl_ui.space_topbar'])
importlib.reload(sys.modules['bl_ui'])

• no effect:


3rd try: *screw it – let's reload ALL modules which can be reloaded:
import sys,importlib
for m in list(sys.modules):
    try:
        importlib.reload(sys.modules[m])
    except: pass

• no effect:


Ok, let's use Reload Scripts:
import bpy
bpy.ops.script.reload()

• In this case the work is done:



• But "Reload Scripts" is SLOW.
So I wonder: is there any way to cherry-pick the UI script I would like to reload?
I thought Reload Scripts just do bulk importlib.reload, hence I could have use importlib – but as we saw in the examples above – importlib.reload is useless for reloading UI scripts.
➤ Is it possible to reload one specific UI-script without using Reload Scripts ?
?

import importlib
import bpy
import bl_ui

bpy.utils.unregister_class(bl_ui.space_topbar.TOPBAR_MT_file)

importlib.reload(bl_ui.space_topbar)

bpy.utils.register_class(bl_ui.space_topbar.TOPBAR_MT_file)


bl_ui.space_topbar has the list classes with all the menu and panel classes.
import importlib
import bpy
import bl_ui


for cls in bl_ui.space_topbar.classes:
    if cls.is_registered:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

importlib.reload(bl_ui.space_topbar)

for cls in bl_ui.space_topbar.classes:
    bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

If you importlib.reload bl_ui it reloads all the sub-modules. Also it has its own register and unregister. But this is a bit slow as well.
import importlib
import bl_ui

bl_ui.unregister()

importlib.reload(bl_ui)

bl_ui.register()

Also keep in mind that user might not be able to edit files in the Blender installation folder because of a lack of permissions.

I actually have had this exact issue before, and this is how I worked around it. It's janky but it did the trick. Feel free to use all or only a portion of this code, I haven't used it in a long time.
It adds a panel in the text editor to select your script and reload it.
It should be mentioned that this won't work if you're trying to only reload a specific python file within a full package e.g. trying to reload space_topbar.py. The script has to have it's own __init__ file essentially that will run.
bl_info = {
    "name": "Refresh Single Addon",
    "description": "Refresh one addon with builtin register function",
    "author": "Jakemoyo",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "Text Editor > N Panel",
    "category": "Text Editor",
}

import bpy


class RefreshAddonProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    refresh_addon_filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="File Path",
        default="",
        subtype="FILE_PATH",
    )
    refresh_addon_module_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Module Name")


class PREFS_OT_refresh_single_addon(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Refresh single addon with built-in register function."""

    bl_idname = "preferences.refresh_single_addon"
    bl_label = "Refresh Single Addon"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        props = context.window_manager.refresh_props
        bpy.ops.preferences.addon_remove(module=props.refresh_addon_module_name)
        bpy.ops.preferences.addon_install(filepath=props.refresh_addon_filepath)
        bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module=props.refresh_addon_module_name)
        return {"FINISHED"}


class TEXT_PT_RefreshSingleAddonPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "TEXT_EDITOR"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Refresh Single Addon"
    bl_category = "Text"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        props = context.window_manager.refresh_props
        layout.prop(props, "refresh_addon_filepath")
        layout.prop(props, "refresh_addon_module_name")
        op = layout.operator("preferences.refresh_single_addon")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RefreshAddonProps)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.refresh_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        type=RefreshAddonProps
    )
    bpy.utils.register_class(PREFS_OT_refresh_single_addon)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEXT_PT_RefreshSingleAddonPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PREFS_OT_refresh_single_addon)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEXT_PT_RefreshSingleAddonPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RefreshAddonProps)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.refresh_props


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Your add-on is meant to re-install custom add-ons, so it has ZERO-relevance to the Blender's UI and to the problem I've described in my question.

@Yaroslav I think it's relevant considering some people wrap their scripts in addons.

@Markus von Broady — It COULD be relevant to some other questions, but not to the one which says: "reload one particular UI SCRIPT", because it just automatically re-installs CUSTOM add-ons, but do not update Blender's UI at all.

@Yaroslav Hello, flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

@Yaroslav why do you capitalize "CUSTOM" - your script isn't custom? It's not clear what "UI SCRIPT" means, an addon is a script, and an addon seems slightly more relevant to UI, since typically addons implement UI, and what you write in the Blender's text editor is just an interface-less prototype.

@Markus von Broady — >> //It's not clear what "UI SCRIPT" means// —  Factually it IS clear since in my question I'm referring to the SPECIFIC DEFAULT ui script (space_topbar.py). I have not only named it, but also provided the full path to this script. In this case any kind of ambiguity could appear only if you are reading the title while ignoring the question itself.

@Yaroslav OK, it is not clear to me... If you think it's factually not true that it's not clear to me then I think we reached a dead end in our conversation. :)

@MarkusvonBroady This script uses addon_remove, addon_install, addon_enable. bl_ui is the native UI code files that are not meant to be removed or installed. The method will not work for the addon's sub-modules. It only reloads the top level file. So if the __init__.py does not reload sub-modules they won't be updated. You would need a zip files to install a multi-file addon and update the zip every time you make a change. If you are not testing the installation itself it does not make much sense as internally it all boils down to importlib.reload or del sys.modules['my_module'].
